# How do I efficiently apply pandas.Timestamp functions to a full dataframe/column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Pandas is a great tool for a number of data tasks. Many functions have been streamlined to efficiently be applied to columns rather than individual cells/rows. One such function is the `to_datetime()` function, which I use as an example later in this question. However, **there are a number of commands in pandas that, as best I can tell from the documentation, do not directly relate to dataframes.** The specific function I am interested in is the [`pandas.Timestamp.isocalendar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isocalendar.html) function, but there are a slew of functions in the `pandas.Timestamp` class (and likely other pandas classes as well) that fit this description and have minimal documentation. **Is there a way to efficiently broadcast these functions to a full column's worth of data?** If so, how would I do that?

Note: I know that I can use the `apply()` function, but this is demonstrably slower (~5x in my test) than what I have in mind. The `apply()` function is also not restricted to pandas functions, so I feel there must be a way to do this (otherwise, why have the `pandas.Timestamp` class at all, when `datetime` does these same things for single values?). See the below code for an example, in which I compare the `pandas.to_datetime()` function to applying the `datetime.strptime()` function to each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from faker import Faker
import time
import copy

# Setting up fake dataframe:
Faker.seed(0)
fake = Faker()

observations=1000

dates=[fake.date_between(start_date=datetime.datetime(2020,1,1),end_date=datetime.datetime(2020,1,31)) for _ in range(observations)]
index=[x for x in range(observations)]

df=pd.DataFrame({'id' : index,'dates' : dates},columns=['id','dates'])

# Converting datetime object to string:
df['dates']=df['dates'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Copy dataframe to run two time tests:
df2=copy.copy(df)

# Speed of the apply() function:
tic = time.perf_counter()
df['dates']=df['dates'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f'pandas apply(lambda) completed in {toc-tic:0.4f} seconds')

# speed of the to_datetime() function:
tic = time.perf_counter()
df2['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f'pandas to_datetime() completed in {toc-tic:0.4f} seconds')

#Script returns:
#pandas apply(lambda) completed in 0.0107 seconds
#pandas to_datetime() completed in 0.0021 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time function can be accessed once you got a datetime64[ns] dtype (which will be created once you have a datetimeindex : for example using [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range) or [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime)).

You can then use the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html?highlight=dt#pandas.Series.dt) to cast all datetime-like functions efficiently:

```
df['dates'].dt.isocalendar()
```

Comment: I see! Based off your response, I ran a similar test to the one described in my question, and the pandas dt.isocalendar() was about twice as fast as applying the datetime.isocalendar() function. So not as much time savings as the to_datetime() function, but still a good improvement.